# Regex to extract shoe size from string column

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a database with string column *product_name* which has data like:

```
Vans Classic Slip-On Black & White Checkerboard/ White - veľkosť (US) : 6 (EUR: 38)

Vans Old Skool - čierna - veľkosť (US) : 9.5 (EUR: 42.5)
```

I am trying to extract the US size...

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR("product_name", ...) AS "size"
```

...with desired output like this.

```
size
6
9.5
```

I have tried this, but to no avail

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR("product_name", '(US)(\d+)') AS "size"
```

Comment: Do you have the chance to change the database design? It seems to be horrible at the moment - This design is just misusing the ocncept of databases and holding clean data - read over database normalization

Comment: The size, color, name and other attributes are also properly stored in the database alongside this product_name. But there are few errors, that I'm now trying to fix by extracting the us size directly from this column.

Answer (score 2):

I need to agree with [B001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59950782/regex-to-extract-shoe-size-from-string-column#comment106021305_59950782), this might not be the best way of saving your information. However, if you are sure your strings are going to have this format, you could use this regex

```
\(US\) ?: ?(\d+\.?\d*) \(EUR: ?(\d+\.?\d*)\)
```

This will match the US shoe size first and then the EUR one.
Here is a visual explaination of the regex
[image: Regular expression visualization]

Please note that this regex will match **BOTH** sizes, I'm not sure which one you prefer

You can test more cases in [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gl7zUZ/1)

Comment: Thanks. As I said I'm only trying to extract the US size. But even if I run REGEXP_SUBSTR("product_name", '\(US\) ?: ?(\d+\.?\d*)') I'm still getting NULL as result.

Comment: @dannier using this string in an Oracle DB with the parameters `(string, regex, 1, 1, 'i', 1)`, i was able to extract the US shoe size. I'm not sure if it will work with your DB though, you might have to alter the regex a little bit or add more parameters. At this point, you can't just copy and paste this expecting everything to be plug and play.

Comment: Also, i feel like you are passing "product_name" rather than the column to your regex.

Comment: I'm trying multiple things, but still getting NULL result. In snowflake "product_name" resembles the column, I'm not passing it as a string 'product_name'. I also tried directly with the first string, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @dannier try to lookup how to use the regex function with matching group, You are looking to isolate the first group.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Your solution works perfectly in Python, so there must be something I'm missing regarding to Snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

When working in the web UI I had to double slash my slashes. Thus the following worked as you want.

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '\\(US\\)\\s\\:\\s(\\d+\\.?\\d*)',1,1,'i',1)
from values ('Vans Classic Slip-On Black & White Checkerboard/ White - veľkosť (US) : 6 (EUR: 38)'),
       ('Vans Old Skool - čierna - veľkosť (US) : 9.5 (EUR: 42.5)') v(str);
```

gives:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '\\(US\\)\\S\\:\\S(\\D+\\.?\\D*)',1,1,'I',1)
6
9.5
```